# Как правильно использовать requirejs?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, requirejs

Некоторое время назад начал использовать Requirejs и сейчас появились некоторые очевидные недостатки и хотелось бы понять что я делаю не так. В данный момент использую следующую логику:

[image: структура файлов]

В config.js - настройка библиотеки и запрос index.js. index.js - файл, в котором я запрашиваю все необходимые скрипты
Проблема в том, что все грузится асинхронно и, например, в шапке есть меню, открывающее по клику, но так как скрипт еще мог не загрузиться, то оно не откроется. Или, например, скрипт увеличения фото не загрузился и ссылка с картинкой открывается по-умолчанию, а не в модальном окне.
Как решить эту проблему? Ставить на все элементы лоадеры и после загрузки убирать? Есть ли какой-то выход? Может скрипты нужно собирать в один и грузить синхронно? В общем подскажите решения

Comment: Показывать глобальный лоадер страницы, пока не загрузятся нужные для работы скрипты. Или паковать все в бандлы и так использовать. Все варианты рабочие, выбирайте тот, который удобен вам. Но многие отдают предпочтение бандлам.

Comment: Можете про бандлы подробнее, я не знаю что это... И что вообще можно использовать вместо Requirejs чтоб не подключать кучу файлов?

Comment: Используете сборщики webpack/gulp. Тут тоже на вкус и цвет. На выходе у вас получается собранный файл со всеми вашими скриптами которые где либо импортировались в приложении. Можно сказать все заменится на `import config from './config'`. Читайте в сторону webpack у него много документации.